# Запуск стартовой активности в зависимости от авторизации

Tags: android, activity, android-preferences

Как запускать нужную активность, учитывая авторизацию пользователя? Например, если пользователь авторизован - в активность новостей приложения, если нет - на экран авторизации.

Comment: Через что вы авторизуетесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать новое `Activity` без картинки (Создать тему NoDisplay), например `CheckLogin` к-рое будет открываться самым первым. 
При логине, можно через `SharedPreferences` шифруя данные, конечно, сохранить введенные после логина данные, и сохранить `boolean` "logged" = true. Если значения нет - сразу открывать активити логина.
Иначе пытаться логиниться к серверу как в `LoginActivity.java`  и если все верно, то запускать "NewsActivity".

Comment: Спасибо, мне очень помог Ваш ответ. Не могли бы Вы еще подсказать, что сделать, чтобы при нажатии "назад" пользователь не возвращался на эту "заглушку"? Возможно, нужно переопределить кнопку "назад"?

Comment: @Андрей , после вызова активити (`startActivity(intent);`) вызовите метод `finish()` у текущего активити. В последствии после нажатия кнопки назад программа просто закроется. Советую так сделать и после логина. И других неважных активити (например, "О программе") т.к. это позволит экономить ресурсы и программа будет работать быстрее вместе с устройством.